# POST method in PHP is unable to post data to the database from mobile browsers

Tags: php, http, post, bootstrap-4

I am working on a user registration form where I'm storing user's username and password in a database table. My web page works fine on desktop browsers. But when I tried it on chrome browser in android it is unable to post any data to the database. It doesn't even show the echo that I've used in the php. I'm new to php.
I 'm using 000webhost's free hosting for my website.

Here's my code for form:

```
<form action="store.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="input_field">
                        <input type="text" name="rname" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email" class="input">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_field">
                        <input type="password" name="renterPass" placeholder="Password" class="input">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                    <div class="btn-primary btn-sm">
                            <a href="https://mailsenderdemo.000webhostapp.com/">Log In</a>
                    </div>
                </button>
                </div>
                <!--<input type="submit"-->
            </form>
```

And the PHP code I've used is:

```
<?PHP
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $name = $_POST['rname'];    
    $pass1 = $_POST['renterPass'];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxxxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxx";
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Error : ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `new`(`name`, `password`) VALUES('$name','$pass1');";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo "Registration Done Successfully...";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Something went Wrong...";
    }


    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Try This**        
    <form action="store.php" method="POST">
      <div class="form">
       <div class="input_field">
        <input type="text" name="rname" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email" class="input">
      </div>
       <div class="input_field">
          <input type="password" name="renterPass" placeholder="Password" class="input">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"></button>
       </div>
     </form>
    <?PHP
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "xxxxxxx";
            $password = "xxxxxxx";
            $dbname = "xxxxxx";
            $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
            if(!$con)
            {
                die("Error : ".mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['rname'];    
            $pass1 = $_POST['renterPass'];


            $sql = "INSERT INTO `new`(`name`, `password`) VALUES('$name','$pass1');";

            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                echo "Registration Done Successfully...";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Something went Wrong...";
            }
        }

            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

Comment: Actually, i have figured it out recently. But, thanks anyways.